# Push notifications receiving VERY delayed on my android, but other devices receive instantly

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm trying to test push notifications and getting very frustrated with my phone. When I test them on my friend's older android s7, he gets them every time in a second. When I test on my other friend's new iPhone, same she gets them instantly. But my galaxy s9+, it comes HOURS later. I have gone through every possible notification setting on my phone and can't see why they would be delayed. I am sending with priority high and channelId to default. We're all on the same wireless network. Any ideas on what I can change to fix this for my device or why this is happening? I don't want to roll out my app until I figure out exactly whats going on.

Comment: Try disabling all battery optimizations.

Comment: See: https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung

Comment: For some reason taking channel id out completely from my send code worked. Why in the world? I thought I had to send a channel id of default?

Comment: Check if your app is being optimized for battery usage:
Settings > Battery optimization > All apps